# Insert csv file into mySql using php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am using the code below to insert my csv file into my database, when I run it, I get 0 rows affected but 1 row is inserted. But yet in my csv file I have 30 records, I am not sure where I am going wrong. I am using phpMyAdmin on WAMP server.

This is the creation of my table:

```
$query_Customer = "Create table tbl_Customer
(
    customer_id int Primary Key auto_increment,
    customer_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    customer_email varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    customer_number char(10) NOT NULL,
    customer_address varchar(50) NOT NULL);";
```

This is my code for inserting csv file:

```
$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'txt/customerData.csv'
        INTO TABLE tbl_Customer
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY ',,,\\r\\n'
        (customer_id, customer_name, customer_email, customer_number, customer_address)";

mysqli_options($con, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);
mysqli_query($con, $sql);
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) { 
    echo "insert Successfully";
}else{
    echo "Error ". mysqli_error($con);
}
$rows_imported = mysqli_affected_rows($con); // returns how many rows are affected/inserted
echo $rows_imported.' row(s)affected';
```

This is the text in my csv file:

```
1, Billy, billy@gmail.com, 0614569631, 20 House Street
2, Steve, steve@gmail.com, 081269691, 13 Curry Street
3, Leo, leo@gmail.com, 0834569692, 7 Pigeon Avenue
4, James, james@gmail.com, 0714739631, 105 Canary Street
5, Barry, barry@gmail.com, 0821296631, 2759 Kingfisher Street
6, Allen, allen@gmail.com, 0614035631, 19 Bayswater Street
7, Joe, joe@gmail.com, 0845696672, 54 Hamerkop Lane 
8, Oliver, oliver@gmail.com, 0834569631, 9 Bedford Street
9, Queen, queen@gmail.com, 0849999631, 2 Albany Street
10, West, west@gmail.com, 0721398731, 71 Starling Street
```

Comment: Do you have a representative example of you CSV file please

Comment: *I get 0 rows affected but 1 row is inserted. But yet in my csv file I have 30 records* This means that data loading fails on 2nd row by some reason (formatting problems primarily, but maybe some constraint violation, etc.). Load your file using CLI and look for the error message.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have added the image link above

Comment: @Akina I am not sure what CLI is or how it works

Comment: CLI == Command-Line Interface. The console client mysql.exe.

Comment: 1) Provide CSV example as a text, not as a picture. 2) Add `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_Customerscript` output, full and non-changed.

Comment: #2000 - LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is forbidden, check mysqli.allow_local_infile

Comment: That is the error I recieve

Comment: Remove `LOCAL` keyword - the file seems to be already local.

Comment: I have edited and added more in my explanation

Comment: @Akina I have removed local before and I get this error: Error The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement-1 row(s)affected

Comment: Please set your environment correctly.

Comment: @Akina from the research that I have done. I used this to set the LOCAL INFILE ON: mysqli_options($con, MYSQLI_OPT_LOCAL_INFILE, true);

Comment: I dont see any lines terminated like this `LINES TERMINATED BY ',,,\\r\\n'`